# Could not install cron on php-fpm container

Tags: php, docker, cron, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run a cron to excute laravel schedule on an container.
I'm using digitalocean.com/php with an Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    cron \
    build-essential \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I added **cron** on install dependencies path but seemly, it was not installed.

```
docker exec -it 378e8a01b32b bash
$ cron
bash: cron: command not found
```

I checked log at /var/log and /var/spool but it didn't show cron log.

```
/var/log$ ls
alternatives.log  apt  btmp  dpkg.log  faillog  lastlog  wtmp

/var/spool$ ls
mail
```

Comment: use crontab command

Comment: @Aleksandr cron, cronjob or crontab still: **bash: crontab: command not found**

Comment: follow the steps described and attach the results to the question. [steps](https://pastebin.com/XqyFj0nG)

Comment: @Aleksandr the problem is cron was not attached with php-fpm by default. We need to install it via apt but it seemly not installed.

Comment: Can you post the output of `docker build`? Maybe it didn't build correctly and you are using the old image?

Comment: @leeman24 Thanks you for your help. I fixed by rebuid that container.